# Where Can I Find Lens Correction Profile Files (for RawTherapee and Other Apps)?

Tags: adobe-camera-raw, lens-correction, rawtherapee

RawTherapee can perform lens corrections provided it has access to the correct Lens Correction Profile (.lcp) file. These files are supposedly distributed with Adobe software, but even after installing trial versions of Lightroom CC (2015) and Photoshop (2015.5), I'm still unable to locate any of these files on the MacOS/OS X (El Capitan) file system.

According to various online sources, these files should be provided with Lightroom, Photoshop or Adobe Camera Raw, and should be located somewhere under `/Users/silas/Library/Application Support/Adobe`. However, I cannot find them under `Adobe/Camera Raw` or any other directory.

Finally, I've installed the latest version of Adobe Lens Profile Downloader (version 1.0.1), and it doesn't list either of the two .lcp files I'm interested in (Nikkor 58mm f/1.4 and 24mm f/1.8 AF-S lenses). Is the Adobe Lens Profile Downloader software even maintained anymore?

So my question is: where can I find .lcp files for the two lenses I mentioned above, plus any others I will need, so that I can use them with RawTherapee and other programs? Preferably I'd like to have access to all of the lcp files for my camera manufacturer.

Comment: I would try the lens manufacturer.

Answer (score 3):

On **Windows**, they can be found at:

```
X:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Lightroom\Resources\LensProfiles\
```

On **Mac**, they should be here:

```
Applications/Adobe Photoshop Lightroom X/Right-click Show Package Contents/Resources/Lens Profiles
```

**Source:**

- [Julieanne Kost: Where does Lightroom Install Camera and Lens Profiles?](http://blogs.adobe.com/jkost/2014/05/where-does-lightroom-install-camera-and-lens-profiles.html)

Answer (score 1):

**Adobe Camera Raw** for **Windows** appears to store `.lcp` files at:

```
X:\ProgramData\Adobe\CameraRaw\LensProfiles\
```