# Where can I find Adobe Lens Correction Profile (.lcp) files for RawTherapee?

Tags: distortion, adobe, lens-correction

The latest versions of RawTherapee can apply corrections from Adobe Lens Correction Profile (.lcp) files, but where can these be found? I've tried Adobe's Lens Profile Downloader, but it doesn't list all of the profiles available (I know because some of the profiles are in Lightroom, but not found by the Lens Profile Downloader). So my question is: how I can get these files for the lenses (from ancient manual to AF) for my camera manufacturer?

Comment: Do you have a specific example that you are trying to find?

Comment: Is this a different question from [this one](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/83758/where-can-i-find-lens-correction-profile-files-for-rawtherapee-and-other-apps)?

Comment: @dpollitt: I have quite a few of them.

Comment: Maybe asking about a specific one will make this question answerable.

Comment: @junkyardsparkle no, it's the same question, slightly rephrased to remove nonessential info, thinking that all the version numbers made the first question sound more complicated than it is. The question is actually pretty basic: how do I obtain .lcp files for my lenses? I'm curious whether no one knows (unlikely), or there's another concern here.

Comment: @dpollitt: good point. I'm looking for an .lcp file for the relatively recent Nikon 24mm f/1.8 lens (full frame), for example. It's possible to use Capture NX-D to do this, but if I can cut Capture (slow) out of my workflow, I'd prefer to do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where Can I Find Lens Correction Profile Files (for RawTherapee and Other Apps)?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/83758/where-can-i-find-lens-correction-profile-files-for-rawtherapee-and-other-apps)