# Lightroom 6: How do I add a lens profile (lcp file)?

Tags: lightroom

I have Lightroom 6 and recently bought a new Tamron 17-35mm f/2.4 OSD lens for a Nikon full frame. I downloaded a recent version of Adobe Camera Raw to get the LCP file for the Tamron lens and I have copied this into the Lightroom/resources/lens profile/1.0/Tamron/Nikon folder but Lightroom refuses to list this as an available lens profile. How do I get the profile to show in the list as an available option?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where Can I Find Lens Correction Profile Files (for RawTherapee and Other Apps)?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/83758/where-can-i-find-lens-correction-profile-files-for-rawtherapee-and-other-apps)

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using forward slashes, i'm going to assume you are on a mac.

In this case, google tells me that the path your .lcp files should go into is

```
Macintosh HD / Users / [your username] / Library / Application Support / Adobe / CameraRaw / Lens Profiles
```

Comment: Could also go in the main /Library path (`/Library/Application Support/Adobe/CameraRaw/LensProfiles`) as well as the user-specific Library.